# How can I compile sqlite for WinRT / ARM?

Tags: sqlite, makefile, arm, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've successfully compiled my WinRT version of SQLite for x86 [as described by Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/05/howto-video-using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx).

However, I am still struggling how to compile the dll for WinRT on ARM CPUs. I've run nmake with the Visual Studio ARM command prompt, but that just gives me the following error:

```
 C:\sqlite>nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1 OPTS=/DWINAPI_FAMILY=WIN
API_PARTITION_APP


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50522.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl.exe -W3 -DNDEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
 -O2 -Zi /DEBUG -Femkkeywordhash.exe  -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTR
EE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -DSQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH=100 /DWINAPI_F
AMILY=WINAPI_PARTITION_APP .\tool\mkkeywordhash.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50522.1 for ARM

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

mkkeywordhash.c

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.50522.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/machine:arm
/debug
/out:mkkeywordhash.exe
mkkeywordhash.obj
        .\mkkeywordhash.exe > keywordhash.h
This version of C:\sqlite\mkkeywordhash.exe is not compatible with the version o
f Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then cont
act the software publisher.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '.\mkkeywordhash.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that SQLLite doesn't isolate it's target platforms.  That means that there were some x86 binaries built that didn't get rebuilt for ARM.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `mkkeywordhash.exe` with the one from x86 build? Then, rebuild without cleaning.

Comment: yup, that was pretty much it. Thanks! :) If you add an answer, I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work:

1. Compiled the x86 dll as described here:
   http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx
2. Deleted only the sqlite3* files and the sqlitelib (many thanks to Banthar and Tim Heuer for the hint)
3. Compiled the ARM dll from the ARM VS command prompt with this command:

nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1 OPTS=/DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_PARTITION_APP

Comment: what does this do? OPTS=/DWINAPI_FAMILY=WIN API_PARTITION_APP

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the binaries pre-compiled via this project:
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/tree/master/lib/metro