# Build SQLite for windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

SQLite is  available as

> A complete VSIX package with an extension SDK and all other
>   components needed to use SQLite for application development with
>   Visual Studio 2012 targeting Windows Phone 8.0.

But I need to do some modification in source code. 
Tim Heuer in his [blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/05/howto-video-using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) described how to build sqlite for WinRT.

The main part I guess:

> ```
> Build the DLL:  
>     nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1  
>     If building for ARM: 
>         nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1 OPTS=/DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_PARTITION_APP
> ```

What options should be specified to build for Windows Phone 8?

**Update:**

I've tried

```
nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1 OPTS=-DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE
```

Result:

[image: Console]

Also I've tried

```
    nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1 OPTS=-DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP
```

Result:
[image: Console]

Comment: Could [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176978/how-can-i-compile-sqlite-for-winrt-arm) be useful?

Comment: @Enzino There is described a way to compile for WinRT/ARM. The resulting dll can not be used in Windows Phone 8/ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite includes some tools to be built and run during the build process, i.e. *on the platform you're building on*: `mkkeywordhash.exe` and `lemon.exe`. These tools should be built by `cl.exe` targetting your build platform, not your target platform.

`NCC` variable is used to specify the location of native compiler:

```
nmake -f makefile.msc sqlite3.dll <your options> NCC="c:\Program Files\..path-to-native\cl.exe"
```

It might be enough. If another problem arises, find `NCC` in `Makefile.msc` and look around it for more information. E.g. you might have to set the following parameters:

```
XCOMPILE=1
USE_NATIVE_LIBPATHS=1
NCRTLIBPATH (where are your native CRT libraries?)
NSDKLIBPATH (where are your native SDK libraries?)
```