# Compiling SQLite for Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

With reference to the question [Build SQLite for Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074821/build-sqlite-for-windows-phone-8)

I am also having same problem with compiling SQLite for Windows Phone 8. I tried with

nmake -f Makefile.msc sqlite3.dll FOR_WINRT=1

I am compiling using VS 2012 X86 Phone Tools Command Prompt. And also I noticed it is picking proper cl.exe. But it is complaining about missing 'winreg.h' header file. I dont see this header file is  available under Windows Phone kit folder.

*vs console Log :*

```
     sqlite3.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\include\windows.h(182) : fatal err
    or C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winreg.h': No such file or directory
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0
    \VC\WPSDK\WP80\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
     Stop.
```

And also, I checked Makefile.msc, I dont find any specific compiler option available for WP8. I have successfully compiled for WIN RT following Tim Heuer [Note](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=A737583042956228!1940&cid=a737583042956228).

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you with your issue.

***Right click*** on the project where you are getting the error mentioned in your question.

Check for the ***Build*** and in Conditional Compilation Symbols paste SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE

Hope this helps

[image]